# Split row into multiple columns with column names based on repeated string values

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to split rows into separate columns based whose names are based on the different elements in the string and the cell should be filled with the value corresponding to it

for example:

```
 Test
 Students [24] , Teachers [12]                                                 
 Students [24] , Teachers [12] , Liasion [9]                                                                                    
 Students [29]
```

Desired:

```
Students    Teachers    Liasion
24          12
24          12          9
29
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
foo <- structure(list(Test = c("Students [24] , Teachers [12]", "Students [24] , Teachers [12] , Liasion [9]", 
                               "Students [29]")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                    "tbl", "data.frame"))
foo %>% 
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>% 
  separate_rows(Test, sep = ",") %>% 
  mutate(Test = str_squish(Test)) %>% 
  separate(Test, c("type", "amount"), sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(amount = str_extract(amount, "[0-9]+") %>% as.numeric()) %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id, names_from = type, values_from = amount) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

Comment: Your solution reorders the rows in its final output (so the OP's row 2 becomes your output row 1) so it's not quite what's desired.

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, borrowing Yuriy Saraykin's data definition:

```
txt <- structure(list(Test = c("Students [24] , Teachers [12]", "Students [24] , Teachers [12] , Liasion [9]", "Students [29]")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("data.frame"))

key_val <- sapply(txt, FUN = function(x) {
    x <- gsub('\\]', '', x); 
    trimws(x)})
```

Here we're removing the extraneous `]` from the data. We can then split each data row into its constituent components by `strsplit` on `,`, then break each of those components into key-value pairs by `strsplit` on `[`. We can then get a list of data frames, where the first row of each data frame contains the key names and the second row contains the values:

```
key_val <- strsplit(key_val, ',')
key_val <- lapply(key_val, FUN = function(x) do.call(cbind, strsplit(x, '\\[')))
key_val <- lapply(key_val, FUN = function(x) {
                            y <- as.numeric(x[2, ]); 
                            names(y) <- trimws(x[1, ]); 
                            y}
                  )
```

Create a list of unique keys. The values can be bashed into a data frame, but note that not all key names are visible at this point:

```
keys <- unique(unlist(sapply(key_val, names)))
values <- do.call(rbind, lapply(key_val, '[', keys))
```

So use the keys to rename the columns to get the desired output:

```
colnames(values) <- keys
values
#output
         Students Teachers Liasion
[1,]       24       12      NA
[2,]       24       12       9
[3,]       29       NA      NA
```